# Display featured products as first in Woocommerce product loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I display featured products in the loop by displaying the featured products first, regardless of the sorting option selected?

**I don't need to add a Sort by Featured option, Just display the featured products for first in each sorting.**

I tried:

```
function custom_featured_products_first( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && (is_shop() || is_archive()) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_featured' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_featured_products_first' );
```